# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have everything up and running but i kept getting this particular error in my terminal

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:262:55)
```

Everything else still works fine in my app but how can i get rid of this error?

I'm not sure where to what to look for in the nodes modules

Comment: I think you should raise an issue for this on Next.js GitHub or start a discussion

Answer (score 0):

Disable the chrome extension if you have any and it will gone.